# Win 7 boot from eSATA but change drive letter

Tags: windows-7, boot, esata

unlike USB you can boot a fully functioning Windows from a eSATA port.

But the Windows I am booting from all programs in Registry are attached to C:    fireFox, etc.

I can manually edit the registry but did anyone ever make a program that changes drive letters in the registry for such a situation.

I am very excited about being able to boot MY WINDOWS from eSATA and was appalled USB 2 or 3 ports can't just straight boot into Windows like eSATA can.

I plan to use key new eSATA and USB 3/2 Toaster i.e. 
http://www.microcenter.com/product/388246/NexStar_25%22-35%22_SATA_to_USB_30_-_eSATA_Dual_Bay_Hard_Drive_Dock
To form a perfect boot environment. Right now if I Boot from eSATA it loads my fully functioning Win7 environment from the eSATA drive but it gets mapped as a high drive letter say H:

My 2 questions are simple

1. is there a utility that changes all say H:\ references to C:\ in registry and elsewhere with a simple UI or is running regedit and search and replace the only way?
2. Is there a utility that will ensure that the laptop with an eSATA will change say the H: drive to C:

   right now if I have a working C: drive and prefer to boot from the eSATA and choose it on the bios boot pressing F10 it always gets mapped to something high say J: or K: and I want my eSATA to ideally be the C: drive when I pick that boot option?

WHAT I HAVE IN TERMS OF TOOLS:

I have googled a few things but its confusing and overwhelming. I have Bart PE and Ultimate Boot disk and Win 7 Ultimate OEM CDs to help....

Comment: I doubt there's a utility for this, maybe because it's a really bad idea to edit registry entries in bulk like this and risk messing things up, not to mention the fact that you'll never get them all (for example, suppose they're not in REG_SZ/REG_MULTI_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ string format). As for your second question, perhaps there's a way to script a drive letter change using something like PowerShell...

Answer (score 1):

> > Is there a utility that will ensure that the laptop with an eSATA will change say the H: drive to C:

The storage management section of computer management has a tool for changing drive letters.
you right click "my computer", then left click "manage", the "Storage" Disk Management. You can right click on a drive and remove its letter o change it.